# When using SPI interfaced SD Card Reader with MCU, the MCU is the master, right?

Tags: spi, embedded

Hopefully this is a yes / no question. I just want to verify that when I'm using a simple MCU with a simple SPI interfaced SD card reader and writer, the MCU is in master mode and the SD card reader / writer is the slave, correct? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. But we try not to use the terms "master" and "slave" anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by SD card reader/writer? Generally you talk SPI directly with the card; there is no reader / writer in between, just the simple MCU and simple SD card, through a connector.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Unless you are using a special IC to do an intermediate function, the MCU should be the the controller(master) and the SD card the recipient(slave). The MCU is reading data off the SD card, whereas the SD card is just giving out data, not doing any control whatsoever. The MCU is in control.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever starts the communication, by giving CS (chip select) signal(s) and generating clock, is the master.

This is usually the MCU: MCU sends the CS signal and generates the clocks, asks for information or sends a command, and may wait for a response.